# In julia import Pkg failed to precompiling. Why and how to solve this problem?

Tags: julia

I am using windows 11 OS . Julia version 1.8.1 . In this moment all type of import is not working. I tried with precomplete and its not working either [image]

To solve everything work perfectly

Comment: What error message do you get when you add or precompile? Please paste the full error message **as text** (not an image) in the question.

Comment: there is no error message. I run more that 24 hours and still process is not finish yet. Then I tried to install another package and still show same result. Same scream for 6 hours still its done have anything new

Comment: That's pretty unusual. One thing you can try is run `rm(Base.DEPOT_PATH[1]; recursive = true)` in the Julia REPL. This will clear out the Julia depot and make it as if this was a fresh Julia installation. Since you're on Windows, also make sure that some antivirus program isn't interfering with the precompilation, try turning off/exiting the antivirus program during package installation.

Comment: that code give some error @SundarR


julia> rm(Base.DEPOT_PATH[1]; recursive = true)
ERROR: IOError: unlink("C:\\Users\\Robiul Islam\\.julia\\artifacts\\2f6134b43dfae1552839323267f0627b7804fe9d\\bin\\libzmq.dll"): permission denied (EACCES)
Stacktrace:
 [1] uv_error
   @ .\libuv.jl:97 [inlined]
 [2] unlink(p::String)
   @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:972
 [3] rm(path::String; force::Bool, recursive::Bool)
   @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:283
 [4] rm(path::String; force::Bool, recursive::Bool) (repeats 4 times)
   @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:294
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[1]:1

Comment: That may be the source of the original problem (though it's still pretty weird). Whichever terminal program you are using, right click and open it as Admin, and then run Julia within it and execute the `rm` command from above. Then, exit that terminal and open a normal non-Admin terminal and try installing Julia packages from there. (If that doesn't work, it's probably time to ask on the Julia Discourse discourse.julialang.org)

Comment: After few restarts it works; I don't know why?